# Postgres connection pool size going beyond the configured value in AWS. What may be the reason?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, deadlock, connection-pooling

We have server deployed in AWS for our NODE JS service with postgres DB connection pool of size 5.

During the load prod times, the number of active connections spike upto 15-17 active connections in each node...

This happening in several nodes... Have checked the config and environment changes and they are fine...

What to do?

Comment: What are you using for connection pooling? PgBouncer or something using Node?

Comment: I'm using "PG" for connecting node to postgres